# Graph API Explorer and test users

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've set up a test user for my app in the Roles section, switch to that account and access the Graph API Explorer.  From the app combo box I'm presented with the Graph API Explorer app only, never my custom Hello World app... why is this?

Also if I punch in the access code of my test user (while still logged in as the main developer), I receive the following error:

> {   "error": {
>       "message": "Error validating application.",
>       "type": "OAuthException"   } }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've set up a test user for my app in the Roles section, switch to that account and access the Graph API Explorer. From the app combo box I'm presented with the Graph API Explorer app only, never my custom Hello World app... why is this?

The test user account is not (and cannot become) an administrator of your Hello World application. As a result, it cannot access it with the Graph API Explorer.

> Also if I punch in the access code of my test user (while still logged in as the main developer), I receive the following error...

The Graph API Explorer assumes that you are using it with your own account's access tokens, not another account's.

If you are looking to learn about the Graph API and its methods, the Explorer is an excellent resource. If you are trying to test your application, especially with test users, you would be better served by making API calls directly.